# how to loop and save values in array from JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

I'm trying to get values from external json file and save some values in array. My code :

```
$.getJSON("https://link.to.my.json", function(data) {
    console.log(data); // this will show the info it in  console
});
```

So I can get data from json but I'm not sure how I can add first and last name to array [bob rooppo, peter sticker]. Any help would be appreciated 
and my json:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "test": "123",
      "name": {
        "first": "bob",
        "last": "roppo"
      },
      "email": "bob@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    },
    {
      "test": "124",
      "name": {
        "first": "peter",
        "last": "sticer"
      },
      "email": "peter@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) :

```
data.users.map(e =>
  (e.name.first ? e.name.first : '') + //Handles the first name
  (e.name.first ? ' ' : '') +          //Space between the names
  (e.name.last ? e.name.last : '')     //Handles the last name
);
```

**Demo:**

```js
const data = {
  "users": [
    {
      "test": "123",
      "name": {
        "first": "bob",
        "last": "roppo"
      },
      "email": "bob@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    },
    {
      "test": "124",
      "name": {
        "first": "peter",
        "last": "sticer"
      },
      "email": "peter@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    }
  ]
};

let result = data.users.map(e => (e.name.first ? e.name.first : '') + (e.name.first ? ' ' : '') + (e.name.last ? e.name.last : ''));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`

```
data.users.map( s => ( s.name.first || "" ) + " " + ( s.name.last || "" ) );
```

If both property values will always be there, then no need of short-circuiting

```
data.users.map( s => s.name.first + " " +s.name.last );
```

**Demo**

```js
var data = {
  "users": [
    {
      "test": "123",
      "name": {
        "first": "bob",
        "last": "roppo"
      },
      "email": "bob@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    },
    {
      "test": "124",
      "name": {
        "first": "peter",
        "last": "sticer"
      },
      "email": "peter@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    }
  ]
};

var output =   data.users.map( s => s.name.first + " " + s.name.last );

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Don't forget the space between first and last name ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forEach()`:

```js
var json = {
  "users": [
    {
      "test": "123",
      "name": {
        "first": "bob",
        "last": "roppo"
      },
      "email": "bob@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    },
    {
      "test": "124",
      "name": {
        "first": "peter",
        "last": "sticer"
      },
      "email": "peter@gmail.com",
      "phone": "+123456789"
    }
  ]
}

var res = [];
json.users.forEach(function(p){
  var name = p.name.first + ' ' + p.name.last;
  res.push(name);
});
console.log(res);
```